# www certificate not getting pulled correctly - nginx and certbot

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, certbot

I am using a docker stack with nginx and certbot. My domain is hosted on google domains.

I want a domain to be accessible via example.tld only:

- redirect all http to https
- redirect www to non-www

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;
    server_name example.tld www.example.tld;
    return      301 https://example.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;
    server_name www.example.tld;
    return      301 https://example.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.tld;

    root        /var/www/example.tld;

    index       index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$request_uri;
    }

    location ~* ^/(assets|files|robots\.txt) { }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tld/privkey.pem;
    include             /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    add_header          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
}
```

I created the certificate successfully with

```
certbot certonly --preferred-challenges=dns --cert-name example.tld -d example.tld,www.example.tld
```

- http://example.tld > https://example.tld ☑️
- https://example.tld ☑️
- http://www.example.tld ❌
- https://www.example.tld ❌

When I open the www urls Safari tells me `Safari can't open the page "http(s)://www.example.tld" because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "www.example.tld"`

But what is working is:

```
curl -iL http://www.example.tld/ 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 11 Jun 2022 11:17:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.tld/
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

HTTP/2 200
```

What is not working:

```
curl -iL https://example.tld/
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.example.tld'

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

A / AAA records for both example.tld and [www.example.tld](http://www.example.tld) are set.

Comment: **ALL** SSL vhosts need a certificate. Those that redirect to non-www domains need certificates too. Nginx should complain on your config that you have ssl-enabled vhost where you did not configured any certificates. Also notice you need *valid* certificates on them.

Comment: Adding the certificate to the other vhosts resolved the issue. Do you want to post it in an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong and it shouldn't work. Nginx should complain into error log that the configuration of this virtual host is incomplete:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;
    server_name www.example.tld;
    return      301 https://example.tld$request_uri;
}
```

Any SSL virtual host needs to have a certificate. Even if all it does is redirect somewhere. Because it will only issue redirect after it has established a secure connection.

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;
    server_name www.example.tld;
    return      301 https://example.tld$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tld/privkey.pem;
    include             /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    add_header          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000 includeSubDomains" always;
}
```

Something like this. But the certificate should also be valid; you can create a cert which has both `example.tld` and `www.example.tld` as valid names (by putting them both into `subjectAlternativeName` field), Let's Encrypt does this when you create certificate in one shot and specify several domains into it:

```
certbot --nginx -d example.tld -d www.example.tld
```

Comment: I already created the certificate for both domains as shown in the question. Your solution resolved my issue, but what wonders me: There has been no error log for an invalid config

Comment: I suspect "error_log off;" muted it.